# Problems with ActionMailer: 501 <>: missing or malformed local part

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, smtp, actionmailer

I'm having trouble sending mail using SMTP from a Rails app. I have a `Mailer` class:

```
class Mailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def newsletter_confirmation(subscription)
    recipients  "my-valid-email@gmail.com" # this is set to my email 
                                           # just for testing purposes and will
                                           # be changed to subscription.email 
    from        "\"my-valid-helo-domain.net\" <noreply@my-valid-helo-domain.net>"
    subject     "Confirm your subscription"
    body        :subscription => subscription
  end
end
```

When I try to send the mail, I get a `Net::SMTPSyntaxError`:

`501 <["noreply@my-valid-helo-domain.net"]>: missing or malformed local part`

If I comment out the `from` field, the mail gets delivered ok, but with the from information missing (obviously). 
Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Edit: I'm using Rails 2.3.2 and Ruby 1.9.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error code and the description of the error states that this is an error on the mail server.

I suggest you check the mail servers to pinpoint the error.

When it comes to ActionMailer it is supposed to raise an exception if the configuration parameter raise_delivery_errors is set (default in Production but not in Development I believe), so you can check that one and try to resend if it triggers.

**EDIT:**

Here is the solution (it's a Ruby/Rails 1.9 bug):

https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994-ruby-on-rails/tickets/2340-action-mailer-cant-deliver-mail-via-smtp-on-ruby-191

and the patch:

https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/2340/a/104008/action_mailer-ruby-1.9-from-address-fix.patch

Comment: You are right about ActionMailer not raising exceptions in "development" by default, but I changed raise_delivery_errors = true so that I can see what is happening. I'll try with the mail server to get more info on the error. Thanks.

Comment: The only problem is that the mail server is on shared hosting environment and I don't have access to the logs. So I guess I'll have to figure out from this error message. Do you happend to know if there are more than one problem that can lead to this error code/message?

Comment: Did you tried with a different mail address format?

f.e. only "noreply@my-valid-helo-domain.net"

Comment: Yes, I tried different formats (with name, without name) and different addresses. Still, no luck.

Comment: Maybe its this problem?

https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/2853-actionmailer-cannot-set-from-header-with-smtp

Comment: Do you use restful_authentication?

Comment: I *am* using Rails 2.3.2, *and* ruby 1.9 but not restful_authentication. This looks similar to my problem, though. I'll look over it and let you know.

Comment: Actually, it looks like this is the problem: https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994-ruby-on-rails/tickets/2340-action-mailer-cant-deliver-mail-via-smtp-on-ruby-191

Comment: Fine that you found the solution.

Comment: You should add a link to the lighthouse ticket&patch so that I can check your answer as accepted. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

It is a known bug. https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/2340